# Can not read property 'Concat' of Undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js, chart.js2

I am attempting to use the charts.js plug-in and do a combo chart, but I want the line to be on top of the bar.  This is the syntax that I am using, and both my arrays `linedata & bardata` are populated but whenever I run this syntax I get an error of

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'concat' of undefined
>       at n (Chart.min.js:11)
>       at t.update (Chart.min.js:11)
>       at t.construct (Chart.min.js:11)
>       at new t (Chart.min.js:12)
>       at trends:507

This is the syntax I utulize - where is the error?

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    data: {
        labels: labelsarr,
        datasets: [{  
                type: 'line',
                fill: false,
                label: 'Line Example',
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,0,0,1)',
                borderColor: 'rgba(255,0,0,1)',
                data: linedata

            }, {
                type: 'bar',
                label: 'Bar Example',
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 129, 214, 0.8)',
                data: bardata
            }]
    },
    options: {
        tooltips: {
            callbacks: {
                label: function (t, d) {
                    var xLabel = d.datasets[t.datasetIndex].label;
                    var yLabel = t.yLabel >= 1000 ? '$' + t.yLabel.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",") : '$' + t.yLabel;
                    return xLabel + ': ' + yLabel;
                }
            }
        },
        legend: {
            display: false,
            position: 'top',
        },
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true,
                        callback: function (value, index, values) {
                            if (parseInt(value) >= 1000) {
                                return '$' + value.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
                            } else {
                                return '$' + value;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }]
        }
    },
    plugins: [{
                beforeDraw: function(chart) {
                   var labels = chart.data.labels;
               }
        }]
});
```

**Edit**
This is how the arrays are being populated - values passed from php

```
        var ldata = <?php echo $ldata; ?>;
        var values = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < ldata.length; i++) {
            values.push(ldata[i]);
        }
        var bdata = <?php echo $bdata; ?>;
        var values1 = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < bdata.length; i++) {
            values1.push(bdata[i]);
        }
```

Comment: How do you know that the arrays you're supplying are not `undefined`?

Comment: can we have the line that is at the origin of the error, at least?

Comment: @Pointy - if I do a alert(linedata.length); & alert(bardata.length); They both return 24.

Comment: @RomaDoskoch - there is no concat in any of my code, that is why my mind has officially been blown!

Comment: because the error is in the library you are using.... so my guess is something you are or are not providing is causing the issue.

Comment: You have an array and you loop over it to make the same array? `values.push(ldata[i]);` ??? Why?

Comment: @epascarello - in my mind I was taking the php array and creating a javascript array.  Is that not the method to do such?

Comment: @Sidtharthan - I follow the guidebook to set up my syntax - I go here http://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/combo-bar-line.html and right click the page and select view source to get my syntax I use.

Comment: There is no such thing as a PHP array in JavaScript. You dump it to the page, the page renders and it is JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to set the chart  **`type`** in the main chart option, **not** inside the **`dataset`** *(the second one)* :

```
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
   type: 'bar',
   data: {
      ...
```

Here is the working version of your code :

```js
var labelsarr = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
var linedata = [2, 5, 3];
var bardata = [4, 2, 6];

var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
   type: 'bar', //<-- set here
   data: {
      labels: labelsarr,
      datasets: [{
         type: 'line',
         fill: false,
         label: 'Line Example',
         backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,0,0,1)',
         borderColor: 'rgba(255,0,0,1)',
         data: linedata

      }, {
         label: 'Bar Example',
         backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 129, 214, 0.8)',
         data: bardata
      }]
   },
   options: {
      tooltips: {
         callbacks: {
            label: function(t, d) {
               var xLabel = d.datasets[t.datasetIndex].label;
               var yLabel = t.yLabel >= 1000 ? '$' + t.yLabel.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",") : '$' + t.yLabel;
               return xLabel + ': ' + yLabel;
            }
         }
      },
      legend: {
         display: false,
         position: 'top',
      },
      scales: {
         yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
               beginAtZero: true,
               callback: function(value, index, values) {
                  if (parseInt(value) >= 1000) {
                     return '$' + value.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
                  } else {
                     return '$' + value;
                  }
               }
            }
         }]
      }
   },
   plugins: [{
      beforeDraw: function(chart) {
         var labels = chart.data.labels;
      }
   }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```